# After swipe view, start an activity

Tags: android

I am trying to achieve the following in Android API 16:
I want to be able to swipe through 2 screens, after which I have an activity, login, that starts. For now, the login activity displays a toast.
Screen 1--> Screen2 --> Start Activity(e.g. login/registration screen)

I have used fragments as well as ViewPager and managed to swipe from screen 1 to screen 2. However, I am stuck in how to proceed beyond this.

I have used intents to start the activity.This however results in the transitions screen 1--> 2 not showing but I do get the toast message from the login screen. I am not sure where to place the intent or if  I am doing this the right way.

How would I approach this? Any ideas or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: ViewPager displays Fragments or Views, not Activity. You don't use Intents for it. You use a PagerAdapter

Comment: Make 3 fragment in view pager. After third page swipe completely (onPageSelected() method) then call activity in onPageSelected method.

Comment: I think Answer from @DheerubhaiBansal is right

Comment: If my answer is right please vote it.

Comment: I got it to work thanks to Alexi's and Dheerubhai's suggestions and help. Please refer to their solutions for any future queries.

Answer (score 1):

Make another fragment that will be third and use following code:

```
pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if(position==2)
            {
                //call activity
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. I used yours and Alexi's suggestion and it was quite straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

First create a view pager with 3 fragments although the third one will never visibly be reached. Then, in your activity that contains the view pager implement the following listener.

```
mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            if (position == 2){
              // Create the intent to launch the login screen.
             Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity.this, mLoginActivity.this);
             startActivity(intent); 
             }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // If your view pager has tabs you will need to create the intent here as well.
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Alexi. I used your suggestion and it worked fine.

Comment: I have accepted the answer but as I have a reputation of less than 15 (just signed up) it is not showing.

Comment: Thank you, I understand. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please use following custom class alternative of view pager

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;


public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

    float mStartDragX;
    OnSwipeOutListener mListener;

    public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }


    public void setOnSwipeOutListener(OnSwipeOutListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
        if(getCurrentItem()==getAdapter().getCount()-1){
            final int action = ev.getAction();
            float x = ev.getX();
            switch(action & MotionEventCompat.ACTION_MASK){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    mStartDragX = x;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (x<mStartDragX){
                        mListener.onSwipeOutAtEnd();
                    }else{
                        mStartDragX = 0;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }else{
            mStartDragX=0;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
    public interface OnSwipeOutListener {
        public void onSwipeOutAtEnd();
    }

}
```

After then create custom class in view replace Viewpager with Custome ViewPager Like following

```
<com.examples.activity.CustomViewPager                    android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/rcTemp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rcTemp"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/rcTemp"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/rcTemp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/rcTemp" />
```

and in your code initialize as CustomeviewPager and override method onSwipeOutListener() like following

```
 mPager = (CustomViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setOnSwipeOutListener(new CustomViewPager.OnSwipeOutListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSwipeOutAtEnd() {
                Log.d("callledby me","yes");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just trying to gues what you want
please correct me if i am wrong

I think your requirement is like to 
show some slide when user comes to app first time then redirect him to login or register
same as in xender or other application does

I think you are doing right by using view pager to show slides and then opening a login/Register Activity
but your question is when to open login / Register activity.

I think you should put button at your seccond slide/page to go on Login/Register activity.

I have attached a example screen shots of xender applicatin how he is doing that 
he has a start> button at his last screen to go on another activity after slide

If you dont want to put button and user want to go to login/register by right swipe at second screen 
than it is ok to go on other solutions

[image][image]

[image][image]